# Program that prints how many times every character occurs in the sentence

Tags: string

I have difficulties in solving this problem. I try to write a program that shows how many times every character occurs in sentence.
For example: ,,hello"

h-1 times

e-1 times

l-2 times

o-1 times

here is my idea:

```
char sentence[100] = "";    
  cin.getline(sentence, 100);
     char letters[100] = "";
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++) {
    cout << sentence[i] << endl;
    letters[i] = sentence[i];
    }
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(sentence); j++) {
        if (letters[j]==sentence[i]) {
            counter++;
            cout << letters[j] << " occurs " << counter << " in the sentence" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

but my counter doesn't work correctly and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: assume a character is an 8 bit byte.  2^8 possible character bit patterns.  so one approach is for each possible character pattern a loop of 256, if that character matches increment a counter, at the end of the string print the count for that character, reset the count continue through the loop 256 times.

Comment: or you could make one pass on the string 2^8 is 256 make an array of counters 256 deep, initialize them to zero, walk the string, for each item in the string index into the array and increment that counter.  then when done walk the table and print each count.

Comment: Not sure which approach you are trying perhaps the latter but treating it like a string rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

put `counter = 0` in each iteration of cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++) {
    counter = 0
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(sentence); j++) {
        if (letters[j]==sentence[i]) {
            counter++;
            cout << letters[j] << " occurs " << counter << " in the sentence" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It is work, but better and simply using map:

```
char sentence[100] = "";    
cin.getline(sentence, 100);
map<char, int> counter;
int len = strlen(sentence);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   counter[sentence[i]]++;
}
for (map<char,int>::iterator it = counter.begin(); it != counter.end(); it++){
   cout << it->first << " occurs " << it->second << " in the sentence" << endl;
}
```

for this you should `#include <map>`